# Using wmic to get drives space information

Tags: windows, batch-file, space, wmic

I'm trying to get info of the physical drives in a computer with wmic to get something like this:

```
Drive C:
500 GB Total
100 GB Free
20% Free

Drive D:
500 GB Total
100 GB Free
20% Free
```

My code so far is:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption`) do (
echo "Drive=%%a"
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where DeviceID='%%a'"       
get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='%%a'" get Size /format:value`) do set Size=%%x
echo FreeMB=%FreeSpace%
echo SizeMB=%Size%
set /a Percentage=100 * %FreeSpace% / %Size%
echo %%a is %Percentage% %% free
)
```

And my output is:

```
"Drive=Caption
No Instance(s) Available.
No Instance(s) Available.
FreeMB=9193357312
SizeMB=80024170496
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
 is  % free
"Drive=C:
No Instance(s) Available.
No Instance(s) Available.
FreeMB=9193357312
SizeMB=80024170496
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
is  % free
"Drive=E:
No Instance(s) Available.
No Instance(s) Available.
FreeMB=9193357312
SizeMB=80024170496
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
 is  % free
"Drive=
No Instance(s) Available.
No Instance(s) Available.
FreeMB=9193357312
SizeMB=80024170496
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
 is  % free
```

I'm getting to many lines that don't even have a drive and I can't format the value so I can calculate the percentage, or show the values in a normal format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work for you: the code is to be added at the bottom of your batch file, and use

`call :hdd-info`

in your code to display the data.

```
goto :eof
:code by aGerman - display drive stats and bar graph (REMmed out)
:hdd-info    
@echo off &setlocal
set "GB=1073741824"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l
)
goto :eof
:output
if "%3"=="" (
  rem echo Unable to discover the drive properties.
  goto :eof
)
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%i in (
  'mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"").GetStandardStream(1).Write(FormatNumber(%3/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber((%3-%2)/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber(%2/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & Round((%3-%2)*50/%3)):Close"^)'
) do (
  set "size=      %%i"
  set "used=      %%j"
  set "free=      %%k"
  set /a "nUsed=%%l, nFree=50-%%l"
)
echo(
echo       %1
echo Size: %size:~-10% GB
echo Used: %used:~-10% GB
echo Free: %free:~-10% GB
:: echo(
:: for /l %%i in (1 1 %nUsed%) do <nul set /p "=▒"
:: for /l %%i in (1 1 %nFree%) do <nul set /p "=█"
:: echo(&echo(&echo(
goto :eof
```

Comment: Another question if I may ...That drives info is already inside a for loop to get other info ...and when I execute with your code, it fails, probably because of the call command. Is there a way to do it all together without the call?

Comment: Do you want the information in a text file?  The exact way you are using the code will determine the best way to apply it.

Comment: No, I want the info on the screen

Comment: I added a label in the code above - put all the code at the very bottom of your batch script and use `call :hdd-info` in your code to display the information.

Answer (score 0):

As the errormessage tells you, `set` is limited to 32-bit-integers. If you can live with an accuracy of `MB`, you can shorten the numbers like this:

```
set SizeMB=%size:~0,-6%
```

(it takes the string except the last 6 characters)

It may be not quite correct in a mathematic sense, but should be good enough.

Of course you will have to shorten `%freeMB%` the same way.

Comment: changed the code to
    set SizeMB=%size:~0,-6%
    echo %Size%
    set FreeMB=%FreeSpace:~0,-6%
    echo %FreeMB%
    set /a Percentage=100 * %FreeMB% / %SizeMB%
    echo %%a is %Percentage% %% free
But still getting this:
    "Drive=C:
    No Instance(s) Available.
    No Instance(s) Available.
    80024170496
    91933
     is  % free

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic LogicalDisk where "DeviceID='C:' " Get Size
```

Comment: add some explanation as well.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.