# VBS - Trying to display volume name

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, hta

I am trying  make it so the volume names will display next to the drive letter. This code is part of a drive selection based on name and free space.

I'm pretty sure I have to add something into the vbs line, but I'm not sure how to do it. The code was originally made by aGerman and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754588/using-wmic-to-get-drives-space-information).

```
Call :hdd-info
ECHO -------TESTING EXIT------
ECHO      ANY KEY TO EXIT
PAUSE >nul
EXIT


::MUST ALL BE LAST THING IN BATCH FILE
:hdd-info    
@echo off &setlocal
set "GB=1073741824"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size^,volumename') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l %%m 
)
goto :eof
:output
if "%3"=="" (
  rem echo Unable to discover the drive properties.
  goto :eof
)
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%i in (
  'mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"").GetStandardStream(1).Write(FormatNumber(%3/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber((%3-%2)/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber(%2/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & Round((%3-%2)*50/%3)):Close"^)'
) do (
  set "size=      %%i"
  set "used=      %%j"
  set "free=      %%k"
  set /a "nUsed=%%l, nFree=50-%%l"
  set "namz=      %%m"
)
echo(
echo       %namz% %1 %free:~-10% GB Available
```

Want it to display:

[Volume name] [Drive letter] [free space in GB]

Comment: Was the German named "Johh Doe"? If not please provide referral link. Also show what you tried to solve it yourself. Now it reads or sounds like .. I copied/stole your code and want you to work for me while I only make an account at SO and watch bored... Games of Thrones... while you do the work for me.. as long as I throw the "rep" bone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754588/using-wmic-to-get-drives-space-information Original Post
I have attempted to add the %%m variable and then call it in the vbscript. I also tried to pull volumename independently outside of the current code and slide it into the loop unsuccessfully
I don't have all those attempts of code as I delete anything that doesn't work to make the next attempt
I have been working on this for the past 3hrs and figured it is something really simple but beyond my knowledge
This is just a tiny snip of the entire code which I have spent the last month building

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in comment. Please add that crucial "effort" info into your question (near the top of the question). That helps other to motivate to help you solving your question. (merely reviewed your question) Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: if you want to use 4 tokens instead of 3, use `"tokens=1-4"` instead of `"tokens=1-3"`

Comment: @Stephan How do I get the %%m to be transferred into the 3rd for loop. even with that change its still coming back blank on volumenames

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  What output do you expect from this code?  What are you actually seeing?

Comment: I see absolutely no need for the hta/vbscript. Would it not make sense to first determine the size of the `%target%`, then provide a listing of all available `DeviceID`'s with sufficient `FreeSpace` to accept a copy of it. The end user would then just choose a `DeviceID` from that list which is passed to the `RoboCopy`ing process.

Comment: @Compo I will do that eventually, but I just want to display the 'DeviceID' right now as it is important to identify the drive from the 7 plugged in which can fit the backup files.

Comment: @Gary, one of the biggest problems with batch files is their ease of use. The understanding that it executes on a kind of line by line basis causes people to not predetermine an order and structure and therefore neglect those things for later adjustment. _(Then they come to forums asking why their script doesn't work as intended)_. If there's no volume name, _none show on my currently mounted devices from LogicalDisk_, then you'll need to find another way to get it or use another identifying feature of each individual device.

Comment: I don't even really understand why you need to show the amount of freespace, all they really need to know is, "will it fit?". If you only show those devices with sufficient capacity to receive the backup they only need to be able to identify it and TBF, the DeviceID is usually sufficient for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh eyes resolved this for me. Had to change the `tokens=1-5` to `tokens=1-4`

```
Call :hdd-info

ECHO -------TESTING EXIT------
ECHO      ANY KEY TO EXIT
PAUSE >nul
EXIT


::MUST ALL BE LAST THING IN BATCH FILE
:hdd-info    
@echo off &setlocal
set "GB=1073741824"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size^,volumename') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4" %%j in ("%%i") do (
  call :output %%j %%k %%l %%m 
  )
)
goto :eof
:output
if "%3"=="" (
  rem echo Unable to discover the drive properties.
  goto :eof
)
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%i in (
  'mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"").GetStandardStream(1).Write(FormatNumber(%3/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber((%3-%2)/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber(%2/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & Round((%3-%2)*50/%3)):Close"^)'
) do (
  set "size=      %%i"
  set "used=      %%j"
  set "free=      %%k"
  set /a "nUsed=%%l, nFree=50-%%l"
  set "namz=      %%m"
)
echo(
echo %namz% %1 %free:~-10% GB Available

GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk")

For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.echo objItem.Caption & " " & objItem.VolumeName & " " & FormatNumber(objItem.FreeSpace/2^30, 0) & " GB free of " & " " & FormatNumber(objItem.Size/2^30, 0) & " GB"
Next
```

If start the above script `cscript //nologo file.vbs` it will print to the console window.